# solution of Pell equation with continued fraction

Tags: matlab, continued-fractions

we know that Pell equation is  expressed  as

[image]

which in  case of  D is not perfect square, can be approximated by continued  fraction expansion of D, for instance let  us consider such kind of equation

[image]

square root of 61  can be approximated by  following matlab code

```
>> b=sqrt(61);
>> format rat
>> b

b =

    1523/195
```

but i have  question : how can i  assign result in two separate variable ?namely

```
x=1523 
y=195
```

from this site
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-fast-way-to-solve-the-fundamental-solution-of-Pell-equation

i understood that solution are based on  numerator and denumerator, how  can i  assign  fraction parts to x and y  during  the code in matlab? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

While, by definition, an irrational number can never be exactly represented as a ratio of integers, it can approximately represented via such a ratio in finite precision arithmetic.  This can be done through the [`rat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rat.html) function to varying degrees of approximation:

```
>> [n,d] = rat(sqrt(61),1E-4);  (n/d) - sqrt(61)
ans =
   9.5152e-05
>> [n,d] = rat(sqrt(61),1E-8);  (n/d) - sqrt(61)
ans =
  -4.4218e-09
>> [n,d] = rat(sqrt(61),1E-16);  (n/d) - sqrt(61)
ans =
     0
```

It is noted that the final `0` does not indicate true equality of the terms; just equality to the limits of double precision arithmetic.

Comment: so easy thanks very much , i got point,  now what  about if we have like this   2+3*sqrt(2) ?  how can i access  2 and 3?